# Is casting GLib / GTK pointers undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c, gtk, glib

Since *C* doesn't support inheritance, *GLib* / *GTK* emulates it by placing base class object as the first member of derived class object. I suppose it is something like this:

```
struct Parent
{
    //...
};

struct Child
{
    Parent base;
    //...
}
```

Then we can cast child struct pointer to parent struct pointer:

```
Child  *p_child  = make_child();
Parent *p_parent = (Parent*)p_child;
```

In C++ it can be done using `reinterpret_cast`:

```
Parent *p_parent = reinterpret_cast<Parent*>(p_child);
```

But as far as I know it is UB because Child and Parent are unrelated classes.

Is it undefined behavior in *C++*? Is it undefined behavior in *C*?

In *GLib* / *GTK* there are converting macros:

```
GtkWindow *p_window = ...;
GtkWidget *p_widget = GTK_WIDGET(p_window);
```

I don't know what they actually do. Do they use some special operations to make casting defined behavior?

Comment: _I don't know what they actually do._ That's easy to answer: [#define GTK_WIDGET](https://code.woboq.org/gtk/gtk/gtk/gtkwidget.h.html#_M/GTK_WIDGET) but unfortunately not yet the end of the story...

Comment: ...which ended here: [#define _G_TYPE_CIC](https://code.woboq.org/gtk/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h.html#2205). There seems to be a safe (checked) version and a non-safe version but both finally just C-cast the pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

*Notice: This answer is only addressing the C part of the question*

> Is it undefined behavior in C?

No, it's legal to convert a pointer to a struct to a pointer of the same type as the first element of the struct.

Your code isn't valid C because of a missing `struct` keyword but the principle is fine. Code like this is valid in C:

```
struct Parent
{
    int id;
}

struct Child
{
    struct Parent parent;
    int n;
}

struct Child * c = malloc(sizeof *c);
struct Parent * p = (struct Parent*)c;  // Valid because the first member of 
                                        // struct Child is a struct Parent
p->id = 42;
printf("%d\n", c->parent.id;  // Will print 42
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234326/discussion-on-answer-by-4386427-is-casting-glib-gtk-pointers-undefined-behavio).